# In this ray diagram, a plane mirror seems to form a real image

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

In this [ray diagram](https://www.shaalaa.com/images/_4:17984a74a8d74220a4bcb9e27073f7d2.png) the image formed seems to be real with the given position of the  eye. I have learnt that plane mirrors cannot form real images at any circumstance. But at this one it does. Please explain the answer like I'm 5 and how you deduced what you propose.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farcher's answer is correct. But it can be elaborated a bit to make it easier to understand.

[image]

If you observe the above ray diagram for real images, you can see that the real images are formed when rays from the *same point of an object* intersect to form an image.

As your image shows, this is not the case. Rays from the top and bottom of the object intersect at the eye. Hence the image formed is not real.

As Farcher's modified image shows, the rays from the same point never intersect, but diverges. Hence the image formed is virtual.

Answer (score 3):

Some diverging rays have been left out as shown below!

[image]

A cone of diverging rays which appear to come from $B_1$ are reflected off the mirror and the eye focuses those rays onto the retina to form a real image of the bottom of the feet.

Answer (score 1):

When one says that a plane mirror cannot form an image, what they mean is that if a collection of parallel light rays are incident on a mirror, the reflected rays will not converge to a point.

Of course, if the rays are **already converging** to a point when they reflect off the mirror, then they will continue to do so afterward.  That is what seems to be shown in your figure.

Comment: Can I have a source for that? A reference to a book or paper perhaps.

Comment: @AlphaDelta A source for what?

Comment: @AlphaDelta A plane mirror is just a regular mirror with infinite curvature radius, so $\frac{1}{f}\rightarrow 0 \implies \frac{1}{d_o} = -\frac{1}{d_i}$.  If $d_0<0$ (so the object is virtual, which is what you have when the rays are already converging) then $d_i>0$ and the image is real.

Comment: This line: "When one says that a plane mirror cannot form an image, what they mean is that if a collection of parallel light rays are incident on a mirror, the reflected rays will not converge to a point." I am not sure this is rigorous. Even non parallel rays emerging from the same point would not converge in case of a plane mirror. And convergence of rays from the same point leads to formation of a real image, doesn't it?

Comment: The image in OP's question is virtual. The OP misinterpreted it as real image. The rays may be converging, but that does not mean a real image is being formed. Hence I don't thing the above line is necessary.

Comment: @AlphaDelta As I said, you need a virtual object - I.e. rays which are already converging - for a plane mirror to form an image. Presumably I misunderstood OP’s question, but given the wording I think it is useful to clarify this point.